# Select query with inner join with some pblm

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    response_user, patient_name, ipno, department 
FROM 
    response 
INNER JOIN 
    patient_details ON response.response_user = patient_details.id 
INNER JOIN
    key_points ON response.response_key = key_points.kp_id
WHERE 
    department = 'CVTS' 
    AND MONTH(response_on) BETWEEN '12' AND '12' 
    AND response_key BETWEEN 146 AND 149 
    AND response_val = '5' OR response_val = '4' 
    AND kp_belongs_to = '1'  
ORDER BY
    patient_name ASC
```

I want the name of the patients in specific department

Comment: Please edit your question and supply the definition for the involved tables as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data for that tables as `INSERT INTO` statements, the expected result with that sample data, a comprehensive description behind the logic how to get that result from the sample data and finally tag the DBMS you are using including the version.

Comment: try sql fiddle to provide more context about your schema

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use table aliases and precede column names with those aliases, so that it is always clear which column belongs to which table.

Although it is a simple `SELECT` statement (nothing fancy in it), it would be a good idea to specify which database you use.

Saying that there's "some pblm" (is your keyboard broken? Why wouldn't you write "problem" instead?) is difficult to debug. Is there any error when you run that statement? If so, which one?

Furthermore, it would be nice if you formatted code you wrote; when it looks prettier, it is easier to spot the culprit. I did that, and - if everything else is OK, tables correctly joined etc., **OR** might be *the one*, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT response_user,
                patient_name,
                ipno,
                department
FROM response
INNER JOIN patient_details ON response.response_user = patient_details.id
INNER JOIN key_points ON response.response_key = key_points.kp_id
WHERE department = 'CVTS'
      AND month(response_on)BETWEEN '12' AND '12'
      AND response_key BETWEEN 146 AND 149
      AND (   response_val = '5'      --> OR condition should be enclosed
           OR response_val = '4'      --> into parenthesis
          )
      AND kp_belongs_to = '1'
ORDER BY patient_name ASC
```

See if it helps. If not, consider following guidelines I wrote to help us help you.